Custom Fonts Serverhosted fonts in SVG's
The problem:
I have an svg using a custom font. I want the font to be provided by the server. The font is replaced with Times new Roman and does not use the predefined font.
Folder Structure:
- assets
  - fonts
    - DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf
  - image
    - logo-full.svg

Css classes
I tried using @font-face to define the fonts location on the server like this:
<svg>
   <defs>
        <style>
            @font-face {
            font-family : 'DejaVuExtraLight';
            src: url('../fonts/DejaVuSans-ExtraLight.ttf') format('truetype');
            }
    
            .cls-1, .cls-2, .cls-3, .cls-4, .cls-5 {
            fill: #223040;
            }
    
            .cls-1, .cls-3, .cls-5 {
            font-family: 'DejaVuExtraLight', 'DejaVu Sans', Arial, sans.serif;
            font-weight: 200;
            }
    
            .cls-1, .cls-5 {
            font-size: 30px;
            }
    
            .cls-6 {
            fill: #2e6687;
            }
    
            .cls-2, .cls-4 {
            font-family: 'Athelas-Regular', Athelas;
            font-size: 11px;
            }
    
            .cls-3 {
            font-size: 27.08px;
            letter-spacing: .2em;
            }
    
            .cls-3, .cls-7, .cls-5 {
            opacity: .95;
            }
    
            .cls-8 {
            fill: #ee714f;
            }
    
            .cls-4, .cls-9 {
            letter-spacing: -.07em;
            }
    
            .cls-10 {
            letter-spacing: 0em;
            }
    
            .cls-11 {
            letter-spacing: -.09em;
            }
    
            .cls-12 {
            letter-spacing: -.07em;
            }
    
            .cls-13 {
            letter-spacing: -.06em;
            }
    
            .cls-14 {
            letter-spacing: -.15em;
            }
    
            .cls-15 {
            letter-spacing: -.02em;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>

svg
These Classes are then used in my svg:
    <g id="Ebene_1-2" data-name="Ebene_1">
        <g>
        <g id="Logo" class="cls-7">
            // svg code in here
        </g>
            <text class="cls-5" transform="translate(113.33 51.23)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">ecu</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-15" x="53.96" y="0">r</tspan>
                <tspan x="65.64" y="0">e</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(2.81 26.82)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">Com</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-5" transform="translate(0 50.75)">
                <tspan class="cls-14" x="0" y="0">T</tspan>
                <tspan x="13.92" y="0">r</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-13" x="26.25" y="0">ad</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-10" x="60.08" y="0">e</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(59.16 63.8)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">Risk</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-2" transform="translate(114.31 63.8)">
                <tspan class="cls-9" x="0" y="0">Miti</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-11" x="16.38" y="0">g</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-12" x="20.76" y="0">a</tspan>
                <tspan class="cls-9" x="25.18" y="0">tion</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-4" transform="translate(93.71 63.8)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">&amp;</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(74.55 26.86)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">.</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(74.55 51.19)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">.</tspan>
            </text>
            <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(194.58 51.19)">
                <tspan x="0" y="0">.</tspan>
            </text>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>

Usage in Html
this is how it is used in my vue.js component:
    <img src="../assets/image/logo-full.svg" />

What I tried
I ensured that the font is provided

SVG referenced by an <img> element need to be self-contained. You can embed the used font as a base64 dataURL or convert your text to path outlines. As your current SVG text is already quite complex,  I recommend the latter option. Path conversion will obviously bloat your SVG file but it is quite often still more compact than embedding a font file. Besides, you could easily open it in any editor whereas most apps can't read embedded fonts. See also "Why is my SVG file not using my font file?"
